# Base fee determination in Polygon / tâtonnement

Tags: polygon, fees

I am currently stuck in my understanding of the **base fee pricing**. According to the [wiki](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/gas/#block-sizestrong text) of the Ethereum mainnet, the base fee is penalized if network load is high that would generally result in larger blocks (above block size target) and lowered in the other case of lower network demand.

The underlying mechanism is in my understanding called **tâtonnement** and penalizes every block above the target block size with 12.5% relative to the prior block's base fee. If the block does not reach its absolute block size limit of 30m gas in Ethereum but exceeds its block size target of 15m gas, then the penalty is only applicable according to the fraction of target size overshoot.

**Questions**:

How are base fees determined in Polyong PoS? Now my question is **whether in Polygon the base fee is priced accordingly**? Do the same penalty/award rates of 12.5% apply? Where is this document? On the wiki? On the Github repository?

IMO the same underlying principle should apply to Polygon as well except for the fact that Polygon has a floor of 30 Gwei on the base fee to tackle spammers.

Would appreciate any pointers!

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for the same information, and the only thing I found was in the Polygon forum: https://forum.polygon.technology/t/impact-of-eip1559-and-future-possibilities/1749.

But nothing in their documentation. If you found some fresher news, may you share it :) !